# I want to run cut command to extract some column from a large file and paste it to other file:

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cut

I want to extract some columns from a file and paste to another file. I am currently using:

```
cat $Input_file | cut -f$Var_ColumnNo1,$Var_ColumnNo2,$Var_ColumnNo1 -d"," > $OUTPUT_file
```

but this command is taking to much time on large files (e.g. on a 50 MB file, it is taking approximately 2 sec), and makes my scripts very slow since I need to run this operation many times.

Is there any efficient method to do this?

Comment: By the way, 2sec for a 50M file seems very strange. That's not a very large file. Are you maybe running this in a shell loop?

Comment: To best answer your question, it would be interesting to know why you run this command so many times. Many times on the same file? If yes, how does the file change between two runs of your command?

Comment: no need for `cat`.  Instead can use `cut -f$Var_ColumnNo1,$Var_ColumnNo2,$Var_ColumnNo1 -d"," $Input_File > $OUTPUT_file`.  Not saying that'll be quicker, but it's an unnecessary step/process otherwise.

Answer (score 8):

Not really, no. `cut` is almost certainly the fastest way to do this. I tested some alternatives on a 157M file and `cut` is clearly the fastest (by the way, you don't need `cat` here):

```
$ time cut -f 2,6,8 -d ',' file > /dev/null 

real    0m0.859s
user    0m0.803s
sys     0m0.053s

$ time awk -F, '{print $2,$6,$8}'  file > /dev/null 

real    0m5.442s
user    0m5.317s
sys     0m0.050s

$ time perl -F, -lane 'print "@F[1,5,7]"' file > /dev/null 

real    0m6.065s
user    0m5.943s
sys     0m0.070s
```

If you want to speed things up, you will need to change what your script is doing. I suggest you ask another question, include an example of your input file and explain what your final objective is. If you "need to run this operation several times", then you are almost certainly doing it wrong. Your input file should only be read once, whenever possible.